# vertical align heading with flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, header, vertical-alignment

In this excercise i expect to put header h2 on the same vertical line with the first card from left. each card is a flex item width width 160px in a flex container gap 44px. I can set margin left for h2 to make it align with the card but that wont make h2 responsive. please someone show me how to fix this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.flex, .product .cards .card .square .new, .product .cards .card .square .sale, .product .cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 140px;
}
.product h2 {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.product .cards {
  gap: 44px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.product .cards .card {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #dfe5e8;
}
.product .cards .card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.product .cards .card .square {
  height: 200px;
  background: #f0f3f2;
  position: relative;
}
.product .cards .card .square .badget {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.product .cards .card .square .sale {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  background: #00bcd4;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.product .cards .card .square .new {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  background: #393d50;
  position: absolute;
  left: 123px;
  bottom: 78px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.product .cards .card .content {
  padding: 27px 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.product .cards .card .content .name {
  padding: 0;
  color: #b4bdc3;
}
.product .cards .card .content .price {
  color: #00bcd4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ship_total .ship select,
.ship_total .ship input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ship_total .ship .zip {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .ship_total .ship button {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ship_total .total table {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .product .cards {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=page.css.map */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/page.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
     
      <div class="product">
        <h2>you may be interested in</h2>
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <p class="name">denim classy shorts</p>
              <p class="price">$35.00-$89.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="square">
              <div class="badget">
                <div class="sale">sale!</div>
                <div class="new">new</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <p class="name">golden heels</p>
              <p class="price">$89.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <p class="name">black impression</p>
              <p class="price">$259.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <p class="name">denim classy shorts</p>
              <p class="price">$35.00-$89.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <p class="name">golden heels</p>
              <p class="price">$89.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <p class="name">black impression</p>
              <p class="price">$259.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the proper fix. But Just try it.

Your Card width is - 160px Gap between cards is - 44px

So just align header and cards in middle and give header's width using calc to match below mentioned cards. In your CSS code, can you add `align-items:center;` in `.product` class and `width: calc((6 * 160px) + (5 * 44px));` in `.product h2` class ?

Comment: @KaushikC thanks your answer is correct. I set .product as display flex flex-direction column align-items center, set width h2 1180px  and that makes h2 aligh with content below